# Broken C pointer in Objective-C Header

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, pointers, header

I have a CGFloat pointer in my header that is used to point at a CGFloat array. I declare it like that: `CGFloat* pointer;`. In the initialization I try to set the pointer using this code:

```
CGFloat newArray[2] = {
            0.0f, 1.0f,
        };

        pointer = newArray;
```

This "actually" works. I don't get any compiler errors and stuff. When i print the second value of the array right after setting the pointer with this code: `printf("%f", pointer[1]);`
I get the right result (1.000000). However, when I print the second value of the array in the method called next i get 0.000000 which means that the pointer doesn't point at the array anymore.

I've got two questions. How do I fix this problem and why does the pointer work right after setting it but "forgets" its value again?

Comment: You need to declare it `extern CGFloat *pointer;` in the header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGFloat newArray[2] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f,
    };
```

Array indices start at 0.  `pointer[1]` prints the *second* element in the array, not the first.  `pointer[2]` is off the end of the array.

```
CGFloat newArray[2] = {0,0};
newArray[0]; // this is the 1st item
newArray[1]; // this is the 2nd item
newArray[2]; // this is nonsense.
```

Note that if you try to pass `newArray` somewhere with the intention of using it later, it'll be badness.   `newArray` is on the stack and will be destroyed when the scope is destroyed.

If you want a function that returns an array of two floats, you'd do:

```
 CGFloat *two_of_these() {
     CGFloat *newArray = malloc(2 * sizeof(CGFLoat));
     newArray[0] = 42.0;
     newArray[1] = 59.4;
     return newArray;
 }
```

Just make sure and call `free` on that return value later.  Note that it is exceedingly rare to allocate something so small.  Typically, it'll be a structure that is returned directly.  See `CGPoint`, `CGRect`, `NSRange`, etc....

Comment: Well, the array doesn't have to be so small. It depends on the properties but it also can contain 5 or 10 floats.

Comment: 5 or 10? Yeah -- that'd typically be a malloc'd buffer.   Or an object;  at some point, you might want to consider wrapping whatever it is in an object if you need additional business logic around it.

Answer (score 1):

Larcus, `newArray` is being initialized on the stack in a non-global scope.  The memory for your array is allocated in the one particular scope.  When you call another method then `CGFloat* pointer` is no longer pointing to `newArray` because `newArray` may or may not exist at this point.  If the second method isn't being called from within the first scope then strictly `newArray` will have been deallocated from its original stack frame.  Instead, assign pointer like this `pointer = new CGFloat[2]; pointer[0] = 0.0; pointer[1] = 1.0;`

I think this is the only way to guarantee that the memory you are allocating will be allocated on the heap and not randomly overwritten or un-scoped.

See Wikipedia on [Dangling Pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)

The punchline is that if you do not allocate memory using either `malloc` or `new` and assign that memory to a pointer, the state of that memory will be undefined.  Only `malloc` and `new` can initialize memory in a way that will persist permanently across all scopes of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get array indices from bbum's answer.  'pointer' points to an address.  You set it to the address of newArray, but newArray isn't guaranteed to be around when your second method is called.

Comment: Okay, that would explain why it isn't working anymore after leaving the method. However, do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: One way would be to declare newArray as static at the top of your .m file.  Another, if this is being done in a class, would be to make newArray an instance variable of your class.

Answer (score 0):

In general seems like [lifetime](http://aelinik.free.fr/c/ch14.htm) of the `newArray` is shorter then the `pointer`, so the pointer becomes invalid on a second call. To solve this, you need to move initialisation var, so it will have same lifetime as `pointer`. The other solution would be memory allocation at runtime (using `malloc` etc.), and free it after usage.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the first method a little but more. I'm quite new to tthe raw c coding.